# Install-Shield 2010 SP1 Not opening on windows 7

Tags: installshield

My install-shield 2010 is not opening only the splash screen is opened , it was working fine earlier.I have uninstalled it and deleted all the files in app-data,program-files and the registry,im confused if some other app might be blocking this EXE to run (Because it was working properly earlier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happen to me from time to time, the problems is usually because the auto reactivation of my licence failed.

their's a tools for that called `TSConfig.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015\System`.

If it's not that, you can still check in the InstallShield.log in the same directory, it might give you more clues.

**EDIT :** 
I Just found the email that the Flexera support send me back in the day

1. Close InstallShield
2. Locate tsconfig.exe on the machine (the default location is:
   C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2011\System)
3. From a command prompt, run the following command: `tsconfig.exe /return`
4. Launch InstallShield
5. If prompted proceed with activation using serial
   number

Comment: Thanks for the comments will do as u said

Comment: I Just found the email that the Flexera support send me back in the day
1. Close InstallShield

2. Locate tsconfig.exe on the machine (the default location is: C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2011\System) 

3. From a command prompt, run the following command: 
tsconfig.exe /return 

4. Launch InstallShield 

5. If prompted proceed with activation using serial number